# Remove item from Array typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, enums

I am stuck in a situation.
I have an array

```
arr: [
              {
                "a": "1"
          },
          {
            "b": "4"
          },
          {
            "c": "6"
          },
          {
            "d": "9"
          }
]
```

and an array

```
[a,c]
```

I want my output an array which have only a and c as per array. Can someone please suggest.

Output desired

```
arr: [
                {
                  "a": "1"
            },
            {
              "c": "6"
            }
]
```

Comment: Loop and [`obj.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Comment: Enums are constants by definition.  Also if they could be changed at runtime, the IDE could not give you any help with the statical analysis. 
For me it looks like enum is the wrong datatype in your case. Why does it have to be an enum?

Comment: Your enum is not an enum. It's an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have to apply a filter to `arr1` and check if the key of `arr1` is there in `arr2` like:**

```js
let arr1 = [
  {
    a: '1'
  },
  {
    b: '4'
  },
  {
    c: '6'
  },
  {
    d: '9'
  }
];
let arr2 = ['a', 'c'];

let result = arr1.filter(item => arr2.includes(Object.keys(item)[0]));
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

#### I think you have to do something like this

```js
let arr1 = [
              {
                "a": "1"
          },
          {
            "b": "4"
          },
          {
            "c": "6"
          },
          {
            "d": "9"
          }
];
let arr2 = ["a","c"];
let result = []
for(let obj of arr1){
  for(let key of arr2){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      result.push(obj);
      break;
    }
  }
}
alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```